# CSS current page nav bar color change

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm working on an assignment that has a page with a vertical nav bar in which each of the links are enclosed in a box. The assignment requires that the current link's box be changed to red. I have tried several different methods but none of them seem to work. This is what I have:

```css
   /* the styles for the elements */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html {
 background-color: white;
}
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #931420;
    background-color: #fffded;
}
a:focus, a:hover {
 font-style: italic;
}
/* the styles for the header */
header {
 padding: 1.5em 0 2em 0;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #931420;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #f6bb73 0%, #f6bb73 30%, white 50%, #f6bb73 80%, #f6bb73 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #f6bb73 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #f6bb73 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #f6bb73 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #f6bb73 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(
     30deg, #f6bb73 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #f6bb73 100%);
}
header h2 {
 font-size: 175%;
 color: #800000;
}
header h3 {
 font-size: 130%;
 font-style: italic;
}
header img {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 30px;
}
.shadow {
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #800000;
}
/* the styles for the main content */
main {
 clear: left;
}

/* the styles for the section */
section {
 width: 575px;
 float: right;
 padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}
section h1 {
 color: #800000;
 font-size: 150%;
 padding-top: .5em;
 margin: 0;
}
section p {
 padding-bottom: .5em;
}

#boldp{
 font-weight: bold;
}
#navlist .current{
 background-color: #800000;
}
#navlist ul li{
 margin: 5px;
 background-image: url("../images/right.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 95%;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius:25px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 175px;
 height: 35px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #800000;

}

#navlist ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 10px;
}

/* the styles for the article */
article {
 padding: .5em 0;
}
article h2 {
 font-size: 115%;
 padding: 0 0 .25em 0;
}
article img {
 float: right;
 margin: .5em 0 1em 1em;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

/* the styles for the aside */
aside {
 width: 215px;
 float: right;
 padding: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
aside h2 {
 color: #800000;
 font-size: 130%;
 padding: .6em 0 .25em 0;
}

aside h3 {
 font-size: 105%;
 padding-bottom: .25em;
}
aside img {
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}

/* the styles for the footer */
footer {
 background-color: #931420;
 clear: both;

}
footer p {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<aside>
   <h2>Guest speakers</h2>
   <nav id ="navlist">
    <ul>
     <li><h3><a href="c06x_toobin.html">October<br>Jeffrey Toobin</a></h3></li>
     <li><h3><a href="#">November<br>Andrew Ross Sorkin</a></h3></li> 
     <li><h3><a href="#">January<br>Amy Chua</a></h3></li>  
     <li class ="current"><h3><a href="c07x_sampson.html">February<br>Scott Sampson</a></h3></li>
    </ul>
   <h3><a href="../index.html">Return to Home page</a></h3>
    
   </nav>
  </aside>
```

Answer (score 2):

`#navlist .current` will target the `.current` class, and you can apply a `background` or whatever it is to that class.

```css
#navlist .current {
  background: red;
}
#navlist ul li{
 margin: 5px;
 background-image: url("../images/right.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 95%;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius:25px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 175px;
 height: 35px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #800000;

}

#navlist ul li.sam {
 background-color: #800000;
 }

#navlist ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<aside>
   <h2>Guest speakers</h2>
   <nav id ="navlist">
    <ul>
     <li><h3><a href="c06x_toobin.html">October<br>Jeffrey Toobin</a></h3></li>
     <li><h3><a href="#">November<br>Andrew Ross Sorkin</a></h3></li> 
     <li><h3><a href="#">January<br>Amy Chua</a></h3></li>  
     <li class ="current"><h3><a href="c07x_sampson.html">February<br>Scott Sampson</a></h3></li>
    </ul>
   <h3><a href="../index.html">Return to Home page</a></h3>
    
   </nav>
  </aside>
```

Comment: There must be something else in my css file overriding it because neither of these fixes work. I'll add the rest to the original post

Comment: @KaitJardine the background change is working in your example, isn't it?

Comment: It is working on here from the snipett, however when I apply those changes and upload it to the server, it does not change the webpage. That's why I assume there must be something overriding it in the css and why I edited the question to include the entire css

Comment: @KaitJardine I mean it's working in **your** snippet, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if i'm understanding your right I think you just need to add a background for the current class

```
.current {
  background-color:red;
}
```